# Checkbox in bootstrap label not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, label

I was trying to follow this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms) to have checkboxes displayed as buttons for my angular app, but something wasn't working for me, the checkbox value does not change, and the onclick function is not called :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('is not shown')"> Click me <!-- Here -->
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I remove the boostrap.js script (or the `class="btn btn-primary"`) it works :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="alert('is shown !')"> Click me 
        </label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I make this working without removing the bootstrap.js script?

Comment: I' suggest to bind that button not via onchange/onclick browser calls but via JS,, can you use targeting via class/ID on that button?

Comment: I get that.. cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add custom css for input

```
.btn-group input[type=checkbox]{
    clip: initial !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 29px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: initial !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xt3b88z2/

Comment: Thanks @Lalji, why is `clip: initial` needed?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `onchange`. Checkbox `onchange` should be more meaningful than `onclick`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="checkbox" onchange="alert($(this).is(':checked'))">Click me
    </label>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @ZwoRmi : You are using `val()`, but you need to use `($(this).is(":checked"));`. See the updated answer!